# Ionic Vue - Master Detail View

Tags: ionic-framework, master-detail, ionic5, ionic-vue

I'm developing an app for PC, tab and mobile, which consists in a list of items. Each item has a detail page. The idea is to display each item's detail page when the user clicks on that specific item, but with different behaviour depending on the device. In PC/tablet, the detail view will be displayed on the right side of the list, and in mobile the detail page will be opened in a new page. You can see the idea in this image:

[image: Credit: Martin Pritchard]

The image was made by Martin Pritchard, who wrote [this Medium post](https://blewpri.medium.com/master-detail-with-ionic-3-split-panes-866293608d47) some years ago about how to solve the same problem I'm facing now. He used IonSplitPane in Ionic 3 with Angular. I'm afraid I can't use this approach, or at least I'm not able to replicate it with Vue.

I've tried IonSplitPane alongside with IonMenu, but the behaviour is not the expected, because I don't need a 'hamburguer' menu that collapses in mobile view. Besides, I've tried with IonSplitPane only and I'm not able to put the collapsible side at the end (as it should be the detail view which hides in mobile, and not the left (master) pane). I'm not even sure this could be a solution, as I need that in mobile the detail page displays in a new view.

Has anyone faced this problem and could help me?

Thank you very much in advance.